# Berger notation for a triple product of tensors

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors, multilinear-algebra

The following definition is given in a paper by M. Berger:

[image: def]

Here, $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold and $S^2(M)$ is the space of symmetric $2$-tensors on $M$. Is there a coordinate-free equivalent for this “triple product” in terms of usual operators?

Comment: Not really. Normally, one would just write it using the indices. Note that the notation is somewhat misleading, since $u$, $s$, $w$ are symmetric $2$-tensors and therefore should be written with both indices down. Presumably, $M$ is a Riemannian manifold, and one index is raised using the metric tensor? If so, then a better way to write this is $g^{ij}g^{kl}g^{mn}u_{jk}s_{lm}w_{ni}$.

Comment: [Abstract index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation) is coordinate-free, though it may or may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: What are you calling "usual operations"?